# Multiple layouts in hapijs

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, hapi.js

I am trying to have multiple layout in a `hapi` application. I have 2 layout files: `account`, `default`

here is my view engine registration:

```
server.views({
    engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
    relativeTo: __dirname,
    path: './views',
    layoutPath: './views/layout',
    layout: 'default'
    //helpersPath: 'views/helpers',
    //partialsPath: 'views/partials'
});
```

by default it grabs `default`, how do I force it for a specific file to show another layout?

I also tried adding it to the view call and it didnt work:

```
module.exports.index = function (request, reply) {
    reply.view("home/index", {layout: 'account'});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [`reply.view()`](http://hapijs.com/api#replyviewtemplate-context-options) is the `context` object. So what you're doing in your example is providing a context with a `layout` property, that's why it doesn't work. The `options` should be the third argument:

`reply.view(template, [context, [options]])`

If you have no `context`, you can provide an empty object. This should work:

```
module.exports.index = function (request, reply) {

    reply.view('home/index', {}, { layout: 'account' });
};
```